# Flask/Werkzeug with Python 3.7 on Cygwin: BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: flask, cygwin, werkzeug

It seems that Python 3.7 on Cygwin has some issues with Werkzeug. I have a complex Flask application and decided to upgrade my virtualenv to 3.7 and suddenly I either see this warning

> 0 [main] python3.7 1642 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed
> by 'bit_generator.cpython-37m-x86_64-cygwin.dll' (0x600000) is already
> occupied

Or it plain just crash with a BlockingIOError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 5, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "/cygdrive/c/py/venvs/cyg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/cygdrive/c/maga/personale/py/venvs/cyg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1050, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
  File "/cygdrive/c/py/venvs/cyg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 339, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
  File "/cygdrive/c/py/venvs/cyg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 183, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 339, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1482, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

It is not clear which part is the culprit. If I try empty my **init**.py it seems it has problems with some import chains (import a file that import another file). I thought one of the culprit was the importing of subprocess, but it isn't.

Is there something I can do to get more output in order to give more information to solve this issue? I can't really copy the whole code here and it seems that a simple project doesn't have this issue.

Comment: (0x600000) adrress is VERY low. Probably a BLODA is interfering https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.bloda

Comment: @matzeri Ok, I suppose I should switch back to python3.6 for the time being. Uninstalling stuff is out of question, especially because the only thing I've installed on that funny named list are core stuff (window defender,citrix..).  Why the low address make you think it's taht the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a proper Cygwin installation the shared libraries are always run at higher address than your fork failure case.

To see the expected range you can look at the base address database.
On my current system:

```
$ rebase -si | awk '{ print $3, $1}' |sort  |head -n 5
0x0003ce2c0000 /usr/libexec/coreutils/libstdbuf.so
0x0003ce2d0000 /usr/lib/texinfo/XSParagraph.dll
0x0003ce2e0000 /usr/lib/texinfo/Parsetexi.dll
0x0003ce310000 /usr/lib/texinfo/MiscXS.dll
0x0003ce320000 /usr/lib/sasl2_3/cygscram-3.dll

$ rebase -si | awk '{ print $3, $1}' |sort -r |head -n 5
0x0003fffd0000 /usr/bin/cygEGL-1.dll
0x0003fffa0000 /usr/bin/cygEMF-1.dll
0x0003fff20000 /usr/bin/cygFLAC-8.dll
0x0003ffea0000 /usr/bin/cygGL-1.dll
0x0003ffe30000 /usr/bin/cygGLU-1.dll
```

so or your database is damaged and rebasing was not performed properly, or a BLODA is interfering in loading your dlls properly.

Comment: thanks. I can't reproduce it anymore since I had to continue and thus used python3.6. I tried again by recreating a venv but no luck in reproducing it. Hopefully this will help someone else seeing this.